# Function outputs differently when executed in console vs by event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```js
function arraySum(array) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     sum += array[i];
  }

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function superIncreasingSequence(length = 7) {
  sequence = [getRandomInt(10) + 1];

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    sequenceSum = arraySum(sequence);

    sequence.push(sequenceSum + getRandomInt(10));
  }
  return sequence;
}

function displaySuperIncreasingSequence(length = 7) {
  sequence = superIncreasingSequence(length)

  document.getElementById("superIncreasingSequenceGeneratorResult").innerText = sequence;

}

const superIncreasingSequenceGeneratorBtn = document.getElementById("superIncreasingSequenceGenerator");
superIncreasingSequenceGeneratorBtn.addEventListener("click", displaySuperIncreasingSequence);
```

```html
<button id="superIncreasingSequenceGenerator" type="button">Generate Sequence</button>
 
<div id="superIncreasingSequenceGeneratorResult">""</div>
```

When I run the function `displaySuperIncreasingSequence()` in the console, the code runs exactly as expected, displaying the following in the div `superIncreasingSequenceGeneratorResult`:

```
4,10,18,32,66,133,272,535
```

BUT, when I press the button (`id="superIncreasingSequenceGenerator"`) on the webpage, a single number is displayed?

Why does the function run differently depending if it's being executed by a click vs manually called in the console?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Nothing about `.innerText = <some array>` changes depending on how you call it, it always ends up calling `join` on the array, resulting in an string with the elements joined by commas. I've added the Stack Snippet for you. Please add `getRandomInt` anything else it needs to replicate the problem

Comment: Side note: That code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare your variables. Not declaring them (`sequence`, `sequenceSum`), in loose mode, makes them globals.

Comment: When triggered as event, the function will receive the event object as argument, replacing the default value `7`…

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
superIncreasingSequenceGeneratorBtn.addEventListener("click", displaySuperIncreasingSequence);
```

That code tells the browser to call `displaySuperIncreasingSequence` when the button is clicked, **passing it an event object for the click**. So `displaySuperIncreasingSequence` receives that event object as `length`. When your `for` loop does the `< length` check, it's false, because an event object cannot be converted to a number, so that ends up being `< NaN`, which is always false.

It's important not to use functions as callbacks that aren't designed for where they're being used as a callbacks — in this case, as a DOM event handler.

You can fix it by wrapping it in a function so it doesn't get called with any arguments, so it applies the default for `length`:

```
superIncreasingSequenceGeneratorBtn.addEventListener("click", () => { displaySuperIncreasingSequence(); });
```